# Fargate Task in ECS is not able to pull image from ECR repository using ECR interface endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am facing issue with pulling docker image from ECR repository and getting error - CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon

In my VPC, i have a private subnet which doesnt have NAT gateway connected. Hence to access ECR, i have created the below ECR interface endpoints and s3 endpoint and associated the private subnet with them,

1. com.amazonaws.region.ecr.api
2. com.amazonaws.region.ecr.dkr
3. com.amazonaws.region.s3

I also updated the repository policy to below,

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
            "ecr:PutImage",
            "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
            "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
            "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I also updated the fargate task security group to allow 443 port from vpc range. But still, am facing the same issue and unable to pull image. Can you please help with the same?

Comment: What about your task execution policy?

Comment: @user2616467, I am facing similar problem. need some help. so, you have created multiple vpc encpoints, each with one of the routes you have mentioned in the question; and these endpoints have the same private subnests associated that you are deploying your ECS services in; and then you associated these VPC endpoints with the main route table of the VPC. and you have enabled DNS names for this? is that it? or did I miss anything? and what should the security group associated with this endpoint have in inbound and outbound rules?

Comment: and will adding this enable internet access to the contianers in ECS or only to the ECS-agent?

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved after changing DHCP options to add AmazonProvidedDNS and also adding cloudwatch logs endpoint.

Might help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I think if your VPC endpoint is correct, You might need to add the below permission with above permission.

"ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"

Thanks

Ashish Bhatia

Comment: I have updated the policy with the above permission. But still, am getting the same error.

Comment: Does docker image url is good? Can you post full error or full task definition.

Comment: Also above policy is task execution policy or repository policy?? which you mention. It should be task execution policy.

Comment: Yes, docker image URI is good as if i run the fargate task in public subnet, then the task is running with no issues.

Comment: I mentioned the repository policy. Do you mean the policies provided in IAM role of fargate task? That has been attached with required policies too - AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy, AmazonECS_FullAccess, CloudWatchLogsFullAccess, AmazonS3FullAccess

Comment: I think you need to provide ECR access also to task so that it can pull.